# how to load html page in iframe every time without storing or caching on browser

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a chrome extension which loads a HTML page in new tab. The html page is updated with new information daily. But when I install the chrome extension, the HTML page is not refreshing daily and the same content which is loaded on initial install is being shown for many days. How can I include a button that delete the cache or local stored page and reload fresh.

```
<div class="sidebar-content">
                <p align="center"><a href="domain/article.html" target="iframe_a">Refresh To get Latest Article</a></p>
                <iframe id="frame_a" src="article.html" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; overflow: " name="iframe_a"></iframe>
            </div>
```

I am trying this to refresh the content in iframe but the page is not refreshed.
please let me know any solution weather to use JavasSript, PHP or any other method possible.

Answer (score 0):

Append a dummy url query value with something unique (timestamp, date - depending on your data refresh rate) to make the it unique in the iframe src. This will make sure the html is reloaded. No need to do anything in article.html to process the query.

Something like this

```
<iframe id="frame_a" src="article.html?unique=1591293600000" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; overflow: " name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```